# Can not fetch data using react redux-toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I could not find any problem in my code , seems all ok. But data fetching is not working.  please help me.
here is the code :

the store :

```
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    counter: counterReducer,
    profiles:ProfileReducer,
  },
});
```

the view::

```
const AllUsers = () => {
    const { isLoading, error, profiles } = useSelector(state =>state?.profiles)

const dispatch =useDispatch()

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchUsers)

        console.log('profiles',profiles);
        console.log('error',error);
    }, [])

    if(isLoading){
        return <Loading></Loading>
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {profiles && <p>all users{profiles.length}</p>}
        </div>
    );
};

export default AllUsers;
```

Comment: Can you share your slice for profiles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Got the solution ,

I should call the fetchUshers() function back into the dispatch function :

```
const dispatch =useDispatch()

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchUsers())

        console.log('profiles',profiles);
        console.log('error',error);
    }, [])
```